# What happens to attached events after changing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Consider this scenario:

2 slightly different pages with 2 slightly different tables: `user-table` and `admin-table`. Both implement pagination. Let's assume this

```
<div class="pager">
    Pager implementation
</div>
```

I'm attaching events to the `.pager`, to the page number buttons, and doing it twice in different files. Each file has a different implementation of the pager (i.e. calls a different controller). The scripts are included in their corresponding page and are loaded after the DOM is loaded.

user-table.js

```
$('.pager').on('click', '.page', function() {
    $.get(...) //calling user-controller to get the results
};
```

admin-table.js

```
$('.pager').on('click', '.page', function() {
    $.get(...) //calling admin-controller to get the results
};
```

Somehow this works and doesn't conflict. Which for me is counterintuitive.

When I navigate to the user page, the `user-table.js` is loaded. After I click on a page number, the event is fired and the content is loaded.

What happens when I navigate to the admin page and do the same? Why does it work? 
After navigation, the 2nd script is being loaded and new events are assigned/delegated. Shouldn't there be conflicts? Are the events from the previous page/script 'forgotten'? The scripts will get cached and I'm expecting conflicts again, which is not the case.

Could someone explain to me the work flow or the event life cycle? What happens to the existing events after leaving the page? I tried googling, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: "The scripts are included **in their corresponding page** and are loaded after the DOM is loaded."

Comment: Why would they conflict if they are not both loaded on the same page?

Comment: `Are the events from the previous page/script 'forgotten'?` Yes. HTML is completely stateless. Only what is currently loaded in to the DOM will be considered by the browser. All previous pages are removed from memory when the beforeunload event fires.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see. And from this `According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.` I assume that by default it will just remove everything from memory. Thank you for pointing to the `beforeunload` event. PS if you post your answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. `I assume that by default it will just remove everything from memory` that's right, each page is it's own separate entity, even when reloading, and no information is carried over between requests by default. If you need that behaviour you need to do it manually, but that's a whole other topic of research entirely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the events from the previous page/script 'forgotten'?

Yes. HTML is completely stateless. Only what is currently loaded in to the DOM will be considered by the browser. All previous pages are removed from memory when the beforeunload event fires.